# Pass ViewBag to _Layout in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, viewbag

In my Search controller I have:

```
     public JsonResult Search(string term)
      {
         var termLower=term.ToLower();
        var pictures=_PictureRepo.GetAll();

        var productsWereSeached = _ProductRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(term)).Select(x=> new ProductData

        {
            Name=x.Name,
            Price=x.Price,
            Id=x.Id,
            Warranty=x.Warranty,
            Picture=x.Pictures.FirstOrDefault()

        });
        ViewBag.NOfMatchedProduct = productsWereSeached.Count();
        productsWereSeached = productsWereSeached.Take(2);
        foreach (var product in productsWereSeached)
        {
            product.Picture = _PictureRepo.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductId == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        }


        return Json(productsWereSeached);
    }
```

In my _Layout I have :

```
 <div>
    <input id="nOfMatchedProducts" value='@ViewBag.NOfMatchedProduct'/>
  <ul id="realPlaceForSearchItems">
 </ul>
</div>
```

Maybe I should put this code from `_Layout` to `PartialView`. The question would be, how to pass `ViewBag` data from controller to `PartialView`.

Comment: "public JsonResult Search" - so you are already calling your method in ajax, right? You don't need to use a ViewBag.

Comment: Yes, but I am returning 2 productsWereSeached (notice Take(2) part) but I need to send somehow ViewBag.NOfMatchedProduct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "public JsonResult Search" - so you are already calling your method in ajax, right?
>
> Yes, but I am returning 2 productsWereSeached

You already have the result and just need to show it to your targeted element:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Search")',function(result){
    $("#nOfMatchedProducts").html(result.length);
});
```

If you want to return additional information like the total number of records searched in addition to "your filtered results", then you can pass it like this:

```
var totalrows = productsWereSeached.Count();
//filter your search (productsWereSeached)
return Json(new {list=productsWereSeached, totalrows });
```

Then do this ajax call:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Search")',function(result){
    $("#nOfMatchedProducts").html(result.totalrows);
});
```

Comment: No, there can be 1000 productsWereSeached , I am always returning two, but I need number 1000 in my View.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many you return as long as you return an IEnumerable you can determine its length in jquery.

Comment: I am not sure did you understand me, I get result.length 2 as expected!

Comment: So you want to return your list and the count, see my updated answer.

Comment: I am glad you understand me now, your answer is also nice, thanks :)